# Using AWS Lambda and boto3 to append new lines to text file objects in S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to use a python lambda function to append a text file with a new line on a object stored in S3. Since objects stored in S3 are immutable, you must first download the file into '/tmp/', then modify it, then upload the new version back to S3. My code appends the data, however it will not append it with a new line.

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket' 
KEY = 'test.txt'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, KEY).download_file('/tmp/test.txt')
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            print("The object does not exist.")
        else:
            raise
    with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a') as fd:
        fd.write("this is a new string\n")


    s3.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/test.txt', BUCKET_NAME, KEY)
```

The file is always appended with the new string but never with a new line. Any ideas?

UPDATE: This problem does not occur on linux machines or on a Mac. Lambda functions run on linux containers, which means the file in /tmp/ is saved as a Unix-formatted text file. Some Windows applications will not show line breaks on Unix-formatted text files, which was the case here. I'm dumb.

Comment: I'm going to sound silly here but is your intention to write `this is a new string` to a new line of the file? Shouldn't you do `\nthis is a new string` in that case? From fopen() `a''   Open for writing.  The file is created if it does not exist. The stream is positioned at the end of the file. Subsequent writes to the file will always end up at the then current end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.`

Comment: @KeenanLawrence adding a new line character to the front of the string doesn't change anything. i've tried all kinds of formatting techniques and it still never appends a new line.

Comment: Be specific with your issue, do you want the new line shown in Windows applications ?  A newline in Linux file is always `\n` , while in windows, the file use `\r\n`.

Comment: Well, you can simply tell you need Windows program to work with the new line. A lot of people will know `\n` is not a new line for windows.  In addition, if you want the file to work in both Linux/Mac vs Windows,  you need to add a process to detect whether the file is using Unix `\n` or using Windows `\r\n`

Comment: The thing is, \n does work in Windows for applications that are compiled on Windows systems. You can write a script on a local Windows machine that updates a text file from a local directory and it will append new lines with \n. This was a big part of my confusion because I wasn't able to duplicate what I was seeing in AWS on my local Windows machine. But since I now know that lambda functions run on Linux AMIs, the text file the function was saving to the /tmp/ folder was Unix-formatted. So when I downloaded the text file from S3 to my Windows machine I wouldnt see the appended line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download and upload a file in order to overwrite a file in S3; To overwrite an existing object you can just upload the file with the same name and it will be done automatically ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58489223/12739456)). Look into the `put_object` function ([S3 doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object)).

So your code will look like this:

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket' 
KEY = 'test.txt'
# Use .client() instead of .resource()
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # (Optional) Read the object
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=KEY)
        file_content = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        
        # (Optional) Update the file content
        new_file_content = file_content + "this is a new string\n"
        
        # Write to the object
        s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=KEY, Body=str(new_file_content))

    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            print("The object does not exist.")
        else:
            raise
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the local file path

```
import boto3
import botocore
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
KEY = 'test.txt'
LOCAL_FILE = '/tmp/test.txt'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        obj=s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(LOCAL_FILE, KEY)
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            print("The object does not exist.")
        else:
            raise
    with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'a') as fd:
        fd.write("this is a new string\n")


    s3.meta.client.upload_file(LOCAL_FILE, BUCKET_NAME, KEY)
```

Boto3 doc reference: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file

Comment: This does not work. This line:

    obj=s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, KEY).download_file(LOCAL_FILE, KEY)

causes the function to fail because the parameter 'KEY' in download_file() is an invalid extra argument. When I remove that argument the function runs, but it does not write the new string to a new line. It just concatenates with the previous string like before.

Comment: Sorry I copied your code and modified it... The line has been corrected it should have read `obj=s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(LOCAL_FILE, KEY)` Where referencing the `s3.Bucket` object instead of the `s3.Object` is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Nice Post!
Just an adjustment..
You should change the order of LOCAL_FILE and KEY in the parameters of the download_file method.
The correct syntax is:

```
obj=s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY,LOCAL_FILE)
```

Also it would be nice if we delete de local file in case of file not found in the bucket. because if we dont remove the local file (if exists obviously) we may be adding a new line to the already existed local file.
With the help of this function:

```
def remove_local_file(filePath):
import os
     # As file at filePath is deleted now, so we should check if file exists or not not before deleting them
    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        os.remove(filePath)
    else:
        print("Can not delete the file as it doesn't exists")
```

the final code starting in the 'try' could be like this:

```
try:
    obj=s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY,LOCAL_FILE)
except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
        remove_local_file(LOCAL_FILE)
    else:
        raise
with open(LOCAL_FILE, 'a') as fd:
    fd.write("this is a new string\n")

s3.meta.client.upload_file(LOCAL_FILE, BUCKET_NAME, KEY)
```