# Python Boto3 update/overwrite object in S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I can't find Python source code example to update/overwrite an object in an Amazon S3 Bucket.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would imagine just a normal `put_object` will do it.

Maybe you're looking for this https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

Comment: It is not possible to "update" an object in Amazon S3. Objects are immutable. They must be fully replaced and cannot be edited/appended.

Comment: If we have to completely replace an existing file in s3 folder with another file `(with different filename)` using python (lambda function), would `put_object` work in this scenario, I'm new here, please let me know which boto function could be used for this @JohnRotenstein, thanks!

Comment: @pc_pyr Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 16):

From the docs : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object

If you want to overwrite the object you just upload the file with the same name and if that name already exists it'll be done automatically.

Extra note: If you want to keep all historic versions of the object enable versioning on the bucket.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in the other answer if you push the file with the same name it will overwrite it, just for completeness here is an actual implementation using boto3

```
import boto3 

s3 = boto3.resource(‘s3’)

try:
  s3.upload_file(file_path, bucket, key)
except ClientError as e:
  print("Error")
```